# Which file would tell me the mappings in doxygen

Tags: java, c++, html, c, doxygen

I have a `doxygen` generated `html` files. I would like to know the mappings between the original `C`/`Java` file to its `html` counterpart.

I was able to do it with some dirty tweaking of file.text in latex folder. Any other approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [GENERATE_TAGFILE](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_generate_tagfile) feature to let doxygen create a so-called *tag file*. That's just an XML file which contains the mappings. I didn't find a formal description of the XML dialect, but it seems easy enough. Here's one for libstdc++: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/libstdc++.tag

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at doxygen's source code, in particular function convertNameToFile in src/util.cpp. That is were the magic happens.